# Sharepoint to call a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sharepoint-2007

I'm completely new with SharePoint. How can I create a new page where the user can essentially click a button that will call a stored procedure on the same server? Am I going to need to create an ASP.NET application?

SharePoint 2007 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Designer will allow you to put a DataViewWebPart on a page and let you tweak it endlessly.  The DataViewWebPart can be populated from all sorts of data sources including SQL databases so it might be able to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could create this as a webpart. There's a built-in project type for a SharePoint Visual WebPart. Would this be just a single button that always executes the same stored procedure? Does there need to be a list of procedures to choose from? Would the list always be the same, or would it need to be populated dynamically?